CloudPage InsertData() shows 500 error message if data already exists in DE
How can I get the CloudPage not to go to the 500 error page if I am using InsertData() but the data was already existing in the Data Extension? It works the first time if it doesn't exist, but it the error appears if someone goes to the CloudPage a second time.
%%[
VAR @Id, @FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @City, @State, @Zip, @Country, @InsertCount
SET @Id = RequestParameter("Id")
SET @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
SET @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
SET @Address = RequestParameter("Address")
SET @City = RequestParameter("City")
SET @State = RequestParameter("State")
SET @Zip = RequestParameter("Zip")
SET @Country = RequestParameter("Country")
SET InsertData("Member_Address","Id",@Id,"FirstName",@FirstName,"LastName",@LastName,"Address",@Address,"City",@City,"State",@State,"Zip",@Zip,"Country",@Country)
]%%


Assuming here that you do not want to update records if someone returns and changes that information, you can use a LookupRows() function prior to running the InsertData() function.
...
SET @Country = RequestParameter("Country")
SET @validateStep = LookupRows("Member_Address","Id",@Id,"FirstName",@FirstName,"LastName",@LastName,"Address",@Address,"City",@City,"State",@State,"Zip",@Zip,"Country",@Country)
IF RowCount(@validateStep) > 0 Then
   SET @displayMessage = "You have already submitted"
ELSE
   SET @insertCount = InsertData("Member_Address","Id",@Id,"FirstName",@FirstName,"LastName",@LastName,"Address",@Address,"City",@City,"State",@State,"Zip",@Zip,"Country",@Country)
   IF @insertCount > 0 Then
       SET @displayMessage = "Your submission was successful"
   ELSE
       SET @displayMessage = "Unexpected problem capturing your submission"
   ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%

If Id.Member_Address is the PK in your DE, you can just lookup at that value, rather than the full list of parameters.
